# How can rails add dynamically variable lengths of url paramters to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to add a dynamic route to a specific controller in Rails that will allow a url to have a dynamically long list of url parameters.

For instance, if I have links:

```
/cats/display?color=orange&age=7&eyes=brown&shelter=true
/cats/display?color=orange&age=7
/cats/display?color=orange&age=7&eyes=brown
/cats/display?color=orange
```

I am interested in how go about setting this up for routes as well as how do I access/process these parameters that are dynamically added to a link.

Thanks

Edit:

Sorry everyone who have answered, although your answers are correct with what my original question asked, I think I may of asked the question incorrectly.

What would happen if you had urls like this?

```
/shirts/display?product1=tshirt&color1=blue&quantity1=1&product2=polo&color2=orange&quantity2=1
```

where each were grouped into one product like product1 but you could have 3 products listed in one link but then have 10 products in another link. How would you process that?

Comment: The routes for all the above links will be the same. Querystring params doesnt alter routes.

Comment: These are all the same route, but with different parameters, like calling it `cats_display_path(color: 'orange', age: 7, eyes: 'brown')`.

Answer (score 2):

All parameters are accessible through the `params` hash.

If you have:

```
/cats/display?color=orange&weight=10&eyes=brown&shelter=true
```

Then your cat controller can be like this:

```
class CatsController < ActionController
  def display
    if params[:color] == "orange-black-striped" && params[:weight] > 20
      render text: "garfield is not here" and return
    end 
  end
end
```

So everything in the url parameters or POST data will end up in `params[]`.

With custom routes you can create routes like `/cats/display/:color/` which will route `/cats/display/brown/` to the same `/cats/display` and set `params[:color]` to brown.

Answer (score 1):

The routes for all the above links will be the same. You can pass as many querystring params as you want with same route.

*How to access them in your controller?*

You can simply access them in your `params` hash like this

```
color = params[:color]
age = params[:age]
...
```